# In sonar qube scanned bugs & code smells errors is not showing in the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, sonarqube

When I scanned our angular application in sonar qube then we have not able to found see bugs and code smells in the template file. Please what we do that for this issue.

Thanks

Ravi Technical

I have try to new sonar setup and check properties configuration file

Comment: please provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)